# How to return the index or list number from a MS Word ContentControl Dropdown box

Tags: vba, indexing, drop-down-menu, ms-word, word-contentcontrol

I have a content controlled dropdown box created in Word.  I need to be able to capture the index number of the chosen item in the box.  I already know how to capture the text itself after someone selects an item.
That code is: curVal = ContentControl.Range.Text
but I can not figure out how to capture the index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's as simple as:

```
Private Sub Document_ContentControlOnExit(ByVal CCtrl As ContentControl, Cancel As Boolean)
Dim i As Long
With CCtrl
  For i = 1 To .DropdownListEntries.Count
    If .DropdownListEntries(i).Text = .Range.Text Then
      MsgBox i: Exit For
    End If
  Next
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: You are my hero today sir!